# Android RTL layout Direction behavior

Tags: android

I change my layoutDirection to RTL, but in both RTL and LTR direction getX() method return the same number. this method calculate X from left side of screen.
How can I change the behavior of the layout to calculate X from the right of the screen ?
thanks alot.

Comment: I try to use drag and drop.
I dynamically add view (a cube) to my layout and drag it.

Comment: I was asking for `code`, please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

View system in android works **independently** from layout directions! which means ,in your case and any others cases, it works properly and calculates X and Y from **top-left** of the screen!

for your problem there is two approaches :

**one** 
calculate x from right of the screen with like below pseudo

```
screenWidth - getX()
```

**two** 
reverse your code to work with real X.